# Dynamically build table from bean

Tags: java, gwt, javabeans

I'm building an application with a lot of tables (or forms) representing details of a given data row.
Some are quite big and it is not really nice have to add the fields (with handler, logic, etc.) one by one.

What I would like is to have a factory able to build the form (or table) given a bean.
I created a pretty nice Factory using Java reflection only to discover that GWT does not support it...

Is there anything that could suit my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because GWT's compilation is *monolithic* (there can be no class that'd be unknown at compile-time but used at runtime), it means the code could be generated.

Because it can be generated, it means you can do it during the GWT compilation using so-called [*deferred binding*](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#generators). A GWT generator can use reflection on classes that are known at compile-time, it'll just be a distinct API than `java.reflect` (just like Java Annotation Processors also use a distinct API).

You could thus a common-denominator to identify the classes that need to be taken into account in the generation (e.g. they all implement the same marker interface, or extend the same base class) and generate one table/form for each, and either:

- an interface with a type parameter for the object you edit/render, that could directly represent the generated table/form; you'd create a child interface *fixing* the type parameter and `GWT.create()` your interface, just like `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory`, `UiBinder` or `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` work.
- a factory that would return the correct table/form for a given `Class<?>` object (using a cascade of `if (klazz == Foo.class) { return new … } else if …`); that would work similarly to RequestFactory's [`RequestContext.create()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/RequestContext.html#create%28java.lang.Class%29)

All you would see from your code would be:

- the marker interface or base class identifying the objects that can be *rendered*
- an interface or base class for the generated forms/tables that would be returned by the factory or by `GWT.create()`
- possibly an interface or base class for the factory, that you can pass to `GWT.create()` to trigger the generator and get back the generated implementation of it